# Laravel 8 cannot run npm run dev

Tags: reactjs, npm

I want to install reactjs and vue in Laravel 8. So after

```
php artisan ui react
php artisan ui vue
```

I input

```
npm install
npm run dev
```

and get this error message

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\onlinepaint\node_modules\cross-env\src\index.js:23
    )
    ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\onlinepaint\node_modules\cross-env\src\bin\cross-env.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.18363
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "development"
npm ERR! node v6.9.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
```

I did try `npm cache clear --force` and code above again, but get the same result.

Comment: Try by upgrading both nodejs and npm and then run `npm install`

Comment: I remove and reinstall nodejs and npm, then `npm install` `npm run dev` get another error `C:\xampp\htdocs\onlinepaint\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:93
                                throw err;
                                ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: mix.js() is missing required parameter 1: entry
    at Function.js (C:\xampp\htdocs\onlinepaint\node_modules\laravel-mix\src\Assert.js:13:9)` and so on.

Comment: Now try by running these two commands `npm update laravel-mix` and `npm install cross-env`

Answer (score 0):

Try to update node:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

Then:

```
rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean --force && npm install
```

Comment: tried, but get another error `C:\xampp\htdocs\onlinepaint\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:93
                                throw err;
                                ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: mix.js() is missing required parameter 1: entry
    at Function.js (C:\xampp\htdocs\onlinepaint\node_modules\laravel-mix\src\Assert.js:13:9)`